# AJAX not working with codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I've code like this in my controller, this code i got from example code, but when i try with my table, it not working to populate another dropdown.

My Controller

```
class Bkp extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('modelRegister');
}

function carselection() {

    $arrCarbrand = $this->modelRegister->loadcarbrand();

    foreach ($arrCarbrand as $carbrand) {
        $arrcar[$carbrand->make] = $carbrand->make;
    }

    $data['make'] = $arrcar;

    $this->load->view('car',$data);
}

function ajax_call() {

   if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['make'])) {

        $make = $_POST['make'];
        $arrModels = $this->modelRegister->loadmodelfrombrand($make);

        //print_r($arrModels);
        foreach ($arrModels as $models) {
            $arrmodels[$models->model] = $models->model;
        }

        print form_dropdown('model',$arrmodels);
    } else {
        redirect('site');
    }   
}
}
```

my View

```
     <?php
    $this->load->helper('html');
    ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () { 
                $('#makecombox select').change(function () {
                    var selMake = $(this).val();
                    console.log(selMake);
                    $.ajax({   
                        url: "bkp/ajax_call", 
                        async: false,
                        type: "POST", 
                        data: "make="+selMake, 
                        dataType: "html", 

                        success: function(data) {

                            $('#model').html(data);

                        },
                    })
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="mydoubts">
            <div id="makecombox"><?php echo form_dropdown('make',$make); ?></div>
            <div id="model"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i try to use the example code it working, but when i try to change the variable with my table it doesn't work, please tell which lines i got wrong ?

Comment: try to pass the data like this  data: {'country':selCountry},

Comment: and also you don't have  POST name like $_POST['make']; which is used in your controller

Comment: hi @jothi my bad, i paste a wrong view, please see again on above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to pass the data like this data: {'country':selCountry},

missing semicolon in ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            $('#makecombox select').change(function () {
                var selMake = $(this).val();
                console.log(selMake);
                $.ajax({   
                    url: "bkp/ajax_call", 
                    async: false,
                    type: "POST", 
                    data: {'make':selMake}, 
                    dataType: "html", 

                    success: function(data) {

                        $('#model').html(data);

                    } //remove comma here 
                });  //add semicolon here 
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: hi @jothi, i've been change the view, my bad, i've been given a wrong view

Comment: anyway i've try to use this one, data: {'make':selMake}, but it same it not shown the other dropdown

Comment: inspect element  and view the console error in network tab

Answer (score 0):

Your check your controller function the request should be stopped by using die or exit function,

```
function ajax_call() {

   if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['make'])) {

        $make = $_POST['make'];
        $arrModels = $this->modelRegister->loadmodelfrombrand($make);

        //print_r($arrModels);
        foreach ($arrModels as $models) {
            $arrmodels[$models->model] = $models->model;
        }

        print form_dropdown('model',$arrmodels);
        die;
    } else {
        redirect('site');
    }
```

}

Your ajax request data,

```
$.ajax({   
                url: "countrystate_disp/ajax_call", 
                async: false,
                type: "POST", 
                data: {'make':selMake},   //data should be like this 
                dataType: "html", 
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#state').html(data);
                }
            });
```